# What is the difference between pre- and post- pathing

Tags: 14.04, bashrc

I was trying to add some directory to my path today. 
So far I used to do it using `export PATH=/home/username/.../.../bin`, then a colleague suggested adding `:$PATH` in the end of the line.

I read some stuff online but can not tell really the difference. So what is the difference between these two methods. Which one is safer to use, in terms of stability?

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26047/70524 for a rather detailed discussion of them.